# UITableView header under Table while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a task of creating a somewhat parallax solution. Actually, I have to create the same UI as in Spotify, the sticky parallax header.

[image: Simple sketch :]

I tried doing that with the CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout, but I couldn't get the header to respond to touches, anywhere. It looked perfect, but I need the ability to respond to a button being tapped in the header, so, a no go.

So I decided to do everything manually. I'm currently playing around with the idea of two PanGesture recognizers - the Collection View's one and a new one attached to the Collection View. My idea was to translate the Collection View to the top (it's offset by let say 150px down, verticaly - frame (0.0, 150.0, 320.0, something) and as soon as it get to the top, I turn off the new recognizer and start using the Collection View's one. It's not very smooth and it's hard to keep track of things.

Does anyone have a good/better idea how could I accomplish this? So, in short, a fixed header that can have more views in it with a TableView/CollectionView (rows) that scrolls over it?

I would be mucho grateful for any help! :) (and it would increase my points here so I can finally comment and help other people :'( )

Best regards from Croatia!